# How to read eventObject in .click() handler?

Tags: jquery

I have the following object:

```
function Controller() {
   $(".button").click(this.handleClick);
}

Controller.prototype.handleClick = function(event) {
  console.log("Clicked: "+event.target.id); 
};
...

return Controller;

});
```

Is the way I'm reading the eventobject in handleClick() incorrect?

It seems to work every now and then, while giving empty results most of the time - no errors in console though.

EDIT: I changed the "target" to "currentTarget" and now it works!